# PHP MySQL data retrieve from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

There is 3 tables:

First table (oc_product_to_category):

[image]

Second table (oc_product_description):

[image]

Third table (oc_product):

[image]

I want to list product name, image, price where category_id is 59
to this div:

```
<div class="content" style="">
                <h1>'Product image'</h1>
                <h3>Product name and price</h3>
</div>
```

I am beginner in working with multiple tables.
Can somebody help me?

```
<?php 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = ""; 
    $password = ""; 
    $dbname = ""; 
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) { 
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT product_id FROM oc_product_to_category WHERE category_id='62'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
            echo "<div class='content' style=''> <h1>Orbit does content now.</h1> <h3>" . $row["product_id"]. "</h3> </div>";
    } } 
    $conn->close(); 
 ?>
```

**UPDATE:** price in: oc_product table

Comment: Show us your query efforts??

Comment: <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT product_id FROM oc_product_to_category WHERE category_id='62'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "<div class='content' style=''>
    <h1>Orbit does content now.</h1>
    <h3>" . $row["product_id"]. "</h3>
    </div>";
    }
} 
$conn->close();
?>

Comment: Try this query : SELECT OD.name,OP.image FROM oc_product OP INNER JOIN oc_product_description OD OP.product_id=OD.product_id INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category OC ON OD.product_id=OC.product_id WHERE OC.category_id=59

Comment: Thanks! How can I list e.g title? " . $row["product_id"]. " error

Comment: Its simple, add the required column, like this - SELECT OD.name,OP.image, OC.product_id FROM oc_product OP INNER JOIN oc_product_description OD OP.product_id=OD.product_id INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category OC ON OD.product_id=OC.product_id WHERE OC.category_id=59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this is more a question related to SQL than to PHP. In each table, you have a product_id column, so you can use this as a foreign key. The SQL should look similar to:

```
SELECT 
    pd.name, p.image 
FROM 
    oc_product_to_category ptc 
JOIN 
    oc_product_description pd ON ptc.product_id=pd.product_id 
JOIN 
    oc_product p ON ptc.product_id=p.product_id
WHERE
    ptc.category_id=59;
```

If you make this query using php, you get an array containing name and image of each row matching the given `category_id.`

PS: I did not find any price column.

Comment: Thanks! How can I list e.g title? " . $row["product_id"]. " error

Comment: In my statement, there is just name and image selected. So you cannot display it. If you want to display it to, you can extend it as follows: `SELECT pd.name as name, p.image as image, ptc.product_id as product_id FROM oc_product_to_category ptc JOIN oc_product_description pd ON ptc.product_id=pd.product_id JOIN oc_product p ON ptc.product_id=p.product_id WHERE ptc.category_id=59;` then it should work.